# How can I use a remote database with WordPress and MAMP Pro?

Tags: php, wordpress, mamp, hosts, mamp-pro

Let's say I have a website with a WordPress / MySQL installation at:

> http://re.staging.example.com

I also have a local WordPress installation that connects to the remote database in `wp-config.php`, as hosted on the URL above.

```
define('DB_NAME', 'MY-DATABASE');
define('DB_USER', 'MY-DATABASE-USER');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'MY-PASSWORD');
define('DB_HOST', 'REMOTE.IP.ADDRESS');
```

In my hosts file, I do:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost/re re.staging.example.com
```

When I navigate again to the newly mapped project:

> http://re.staging.example.com

I get this page:

[image]

But if I go to:

> http://re.staging.example.com/re

I then get the website, but it 404's, because 're' is obviously not a page in the database. I need a way to map in my hosts to this subfolder.

All I basically want to do is work locally on my code but utilise the remote DB.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Your hosts file definition is not right, you can only map IP addresses to hostnames. Not ports, not urls.

Comment: update your question to include exactly what you have locally and what you have remotely and how you want to connect to and from which hosts.

Comment: Updated my question to make things a little clearer in light of recent progress! Thanks